# Java random letter generator

Tags: java

I have a task to create a small program in Java that will generate random 5 combinations of small and capital Latin letters each time it runs.
Like aA, Ac, Ml, Bc, Ii;  should be the result.

After running to code every time, it generates only 1 small letter, "z".
I have written the code using the requirements and I cannot use other techniques like random. and other operators. Any clues on how to fix this?

```
import java.lang.String.*;

class CopyOfP3_3_1 {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char mb; mb = 0;
        String symbolRow; symbolRow = " ";
        byte msi = 0X60;
        byte bs = 26;
        System.out.println();
        for (byte i = 1; i <= bs; i++) {
            msi = (byte)(msi + 1);
            mb = (char)msi;
            symbolRow = symbolRow + mb + ' ';
        }
    
        System.out.println("Latin alphabet letter: ");
        System.out.print(mb + "\n");
    } 
}
```

Best regards,
Sandis

Comment: why are you using byte and not char and String ?

Comment: "generate random 5 combinations" ... "I cannot use other techniques like random". Do you mean you need to implement your own random number generator? Right now there's nothing random in your code.

Comment: Your for-loop does not generate any random value, just goes through 26 leters of latin alphabet and adds them to the `symbolRow` variable. The `mb` variable after the whole loop goes through all possible values contans the `z` letter and that's all you do in your code. There is no randomization, no getting upper case values and no concatenation. 
It would be good if you will list all of the requirements (or restrictions) you have to apply to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Math.random()**

```
public static void genrateRandomNum(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int rnd1 = (int) (Math.random() * 26);
            int rnd2 = (int) (Math.random() * 52);

            char char1 = (char) ('A' + rnd1 % 26);
            char char2 = (char) ('a' + rnd2);

            System.out.println(char1 + "" + char2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        genrateRandomNum(5);
    }
```

Comment: That only need be `char char1 = (char) ('A' + rnd1);` The generation of `rnd2` can and should be exactly the same

Comment: Thanks, but is there an option that will generate only 2 letter combinations? In your code sometimes it generates 1 letter combination and for some reason, it sometimes adds "}, ~,{, |" as letters. Any clue how to remove it?